# Idiomatic way to process lists and dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-3.4, pypy

Recently I've been discovering "the Python way" of processing lists, dicts, sets, etc. To this extent I've modified my function to calculate the first `N` prime numbers, let's call it the 'Pure Dict' version:

```
def findprimeuptoG(x):
    n_primes = {}

    for i in range(2, x):

        if i not in n_primes.values():
            n_primes[i]=i

        for k, v in n_primes.items():
            if i > v:
                n_primes[k] += k

    return sorted(n_primes)
```

This function works as follows:

1. maintain a list of primes and a list of integer multiples of those same primes in a dict
2. those multiples should be bigger or equal to some integer `i`
3. if a number is not present in the list of integer multiples of existing primes then it must be a prime and is added to the list of primes
4. increase `i` by starting with `2` (smallest prime), up to `x`
5. return a list of primes

I've rewritten this function several times using lists, sets, but this version seems to be most idiomatic one. It is short and it reads easily.

If anyone would be kind enough to let me know if this could be written more clearly, please comment as I would love to read it.

And now the question: The first version of this function is not so clean and is much more C-like:

```
def findprimeupto(x):
    primes = []
    n_primes = []

    for i in range(2, x):

        if i not in n_primes:
            primes.append(i)
            n_primes.append(i)

        for j in range(len(primes)):
            if i > n_primes[j]:
                n_primes[j] += primes[j]

    return primes
```

But this first version is absolutely the fastest when I run it with a `pypy` compiler:

python3:

```
Primes up to: 100000

Algo: Clean version       , primes: 9592, time: 102.74523687362671

Algo: Dict, Set           , primes: 9592, time: 58.230621337890625

Algo: **FirstVersion**        , primes: 9592, time: 59.945680379867554

Algo: List of List[1]        , primes: 9592, time: 71.41077852249146

Algo: List of MutableNum  , primes: 9592, time: 292.3777365684509

Algo: **Pure Dict**           , primes: 9592, time: 56.381882667541504
```

pypy (ver 2.3.1):

```
Primes up to: 100000

Algo: Clean version       , primes: 9592, time: 29.3849189281

Algo: Dict, Set           , primes: 9592, time: 85.8557658195

Algo: **FirstVersion**        , primes: 9592, time: 1.11557507515

Algo: List of List        , primes: 9592, time: 42.2394959927

Algo: List of MutableNum  , primes: 9592, time: 38.764893055

Algo: **Pure Dict**           , primes: 9592, time: 110.416568995
```

I understand the performance hit 'Pure Dict' version got was due to the fact I did not use iterators in my loops, still the speedup 'FirstVersion' got was phenomenal.

As most of our code will probably end up being compiled in a production, should we write code in a more C-like fashion to and not idiomatic Python?

EDIT:

to remove any confusion whether I should have used lists instead of dict I'm submitting another version of this function which I call 'Clean version'. This version uses no direct access to the Nth element of a list, instead it iterates over lists in what I believe to be most Pythonistic way (btw this version is most similar to the lisp version of the same code :)

```
def findprimeuptoB(x):
    primes = []
    n_primes = []

    for i in range(2, x):

        if not (i in n_primes):
            primes.append(i)
            n_primes.append(i)

        new_n_primes = []

        for prime, n_prime in zip(primes, n_primes):
            if i > n_prime:
                new_n_primes.append(prime + n_prime)
            else:
                new_n_primes.append(n_prime)

        n_primes = new_n_primes

    return primes
```

Comment: Here are the results with pypy3, as expected performance of 'Pure Dict' is much better due to the use of iterators, still 'First Version' as an absolute winner: Primes up to: 100000
Algo: Clean version       , primes: 9592, time: 12.010854959487915
Algo: Dict, Set           , primes: 9592, time: 13.721880912780762
Algo: FirstVersion        , primes: 9592, time: 1.1208839416503906
Algo: List of List        , primes: 9592, time: 8.978854894638062
Algo: List of MutableNum  , primes: 9592, time: 5.507040977478027
Algo: Pure Dict           , primes: 9592, time: 15.005417108535767

Comment: You look like you're trying to implement a prime sieve, but aren't doing it correctly - see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've never seen this method and I don't understand it but it seems to work. I ran his code for 100 and got `[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]`.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist sorry, I should have been clearer - this method isn't ineffective, but isn't quite a prime sieve (which is much faster).

Comment: Anyway this looks to be more about complexity than data structures. Your first method which you say is unPythonic looks very clean to me, and seems to use the right data structures. After all, this is based on two concurrent lists. It is performing simple tasks (append, addition) and only running two loops, the two fors. Your dict implementation requires constantly pulling lists out of the dict (values and items) and then the dict has to be sorted. Dict is the wrong data structure because you're iterating over it 5x as much to get it to do what you want, basically.

Comment: Too jonrsharpe: no, this isn't Sieve of Erastothenes, it's a similar and more memory efficient version. In each pass of the outermost loop, 'i' denotes you found primes up to 'i', these primes are stored as keys in dict 'n_primes' or list 'primes, 'n_primes' values or 'n_primes' list stores smallest integer multiples of primes found so far that exceed 'i'. This allows for a simple test if 'i' is indeed a prime. Namely if 'i' is a composite number, then it must be a multiple of a prime found so far and this multiple is already stored in n_prime.

Comment: To Two-Bit Alchemist: I disagree that I am iterating 5x as much in 'Pure Dict' version than 'First Version'. Both dict.values() and dict.items() in relevant for loops of 'Pure Dict' version return iterators, which performs no more work than for loop over a list and over a range iterator in 'First Version'. This is clearly visible from timing done in pure python3.

Comment: But... access to Nth element of a list seems to be super optimized in pypy and that's what my question was about. If pypy and compilers in general are a way to go then should we be encouraged to use Nth element of a list and iterate over a range(n) or should we use more pythonist way of iteration by iterating over a list or dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you care about performance, 'First Version' is the way to go. You can see what's going on using cProfile.

For reference, on pypy 2.5.0, running `python -m cProfile -s cumulative x.py` with 'First Version' gives me:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.727    0.727 x.py:1(<module>)
     1    0.724    0.724    0.727    0.727 x.py:29(findprimeupto)
 99999    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {len}
 99999    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {range}
 19184    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

OTOH, with 'Pure Dict', I get:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1    0.000    0.000   16.864   16.864 x.py:1(<module>)
     1    1.441    1.441   16.864   16.864 x.py:1(findprimeuptoG)
 99998   12.376    0.000   12.376    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}
 99998    3.047    0.000    3.047    0.000 {method 'values' of 'dict' objects}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
```

which shows that most of the time is wasted creating the temporary lists `n_primes.items()` and `n_primes.values()`.

Now, there is an easy fix for this: replacing `.items()` and `.values()` with their respective iterator versions, `.iteritems()` and `.itervalues()`. However, the result is still much slower than the list version, because dicts are more complicated structure than lists, and low-level dict operations are therefore much slower than the equivalent list operations:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1    0.000    0.000    3.155    3.155 x.py:1(<module>)
     1    3.147    3.147    3.155    3.155 x.py:15(findprimeuptoH)
 99998    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 {method 'itervalues' of 'dict' objects}
 99998    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {method 'iteritems' of 'dict' objects}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
```

Finally, 'Clean Version' is clearly rather bad, since it creates a new `n_primes` list on every iteration. Indeed, I time it at 21.795 seconds.

Conclusion: Creating new containers (lists, dicts, ...) is very slow, avoid it whenever you can. Also, dicts are slower than lists. In this problem, you don't actually need dicts, so you should use lists.